# Why is jailbreaking so easy

Tags: ios, jailbreak

Since the beginning of time people have been jailbreaking their iPhones/iPads (Sigh). Somehow, no one seemed to wonder "why is is the process of gaining full root access so easy?" there used to be this website jailbreakme which can actually jailbreak the phone from within the web browser. iOS is always praised for its security yet there always seems to be a quick and easy way to jailbreak.
On Android, rooting requires that the user unlocks the bootloader and flashes a system app that grants super user access. (With a locked bootloader, you can't touch the system files. And even if you, somehow, could root without unlocking the bootloader, system integrity protection will trigger a warning straight away notifying you that the system has been modified).

So my question is, does the fact that one can jailbreak iOS so easily mean that it is insecure? Second, doesn't this mean any third party could easily gain full access to an iPhone the same way? I'm referring to the FBI vs Apple case.

Comment: What makes you think jailbreaking is easy?

Comment: Jailbreaking is easy for you, the end user. Figuring out how to make it easy is a herculean task that you never see. You only see the end result of many hours of hard work by very bright people, as with most software products. Try taking a look at how long it takes for a working jailbreak to emerge for a new iOS version

Comment: That being true, but he does make the accurate point that it is more effortless compared to Android.

Comment: @korockinout13 all of that stuff happens behind the scenes on Apple as well. As F. Stephen Q mentioned, it's made incredibly easy for the end user. The Apple JBers found a way to deliver a product that can let users with little-to-no technical experience unlock their phone. There is a ton of stuff going on behind the scenes from the point you click "jailbreak me" to the point your iPhone loads back up with Cydia.

Answer (score 4):

## Is Jailbreaking an iPhone Easy?

**NO**! But it's done by a program and that makes it easily repeatable, and even able to be wrapped in a nice package to make it easier for other people to use. So on your end it may *look* or *feel* easy, but someone poured real hours into developing that jailbreak method you're using. It's the same with Android. They poor real time and effort into developing these techniques to root iPhone and Android devices and you reap the benefits if they publish it.

## Does this mean an iPhone is insecure?

**No**! Secure and root are two completely different things. Root means YOU have access to system level tools. Secure means other people DON'T have access to your information. They are *not* the same or even related. Your iPhone is as secure as your usage habits. Bad usage habits? Bad security. Good usage habits? Good security.

## Should I be concerned about people being able to jail break iPhones easily?

**Only if you didn't jailbreak it!** Once rooted spyware can easily be put on there. If you root you need to keep your device extra secure on your person unless you really trust the people you lend it to(even for a few minutes)

## Does that mean that any third party can jailbreak my iPhone?

Only if you physically give it to them or do something bad that gives them control(like visit a link you're not sure about, but that falls under bad usage habits). Specifically what you asked about was the FBI vs Apple case and the only reason it worked was it was an *old* version of iOS on the iPhone 5C and they had **physical access**. That vulnerability was patched. Keep to good user habits and keep a good close watch on your device and it's perfectly secure.

Comment: +1 for `Someone poured real hours into developing that jailbreak.`  It's honestly amazing how many things are so easy for people to do, without people knowing how much time not only went into the application, but also the high level libraries/frameworks and tools that make those/all dev's life easier.  IMO Oldschool devs deserve so much credit for having to do everything on their own.  Got to love our Open Source community, everyone is great to host all of these amazing project.  Shoutout especially to groups such as the `Kronos Group` and `Apache Software Foundation`

Comment: Then buy the dev a drink if you like their work

Comment: I bought myself a nice selection for tonight's workload :).

Comment: @RobertMennell What he was meaning by "Does that mean that any third party can jailbreak my iPhone?" is the fact that some years ago, it was possible to jailbreak an iphone by just clicking on a button from safari. **without downloading any software**

Comment: I addressed that with an edit. The like do something bad like visit a site you're not sure is safe

Comment: The third paragraph makes no sense. It claims: one should be concerned about people being able to jail break, only if one didn't jailbreak it... On top of that the explanation mentions lending the phone which has noting to do with the caption.

Comment: @techraf if my phone isn't jailbroken, and I give it to someone, and it comes back jailbroken, shouldn't I be concerned?

Comment: And if your phone is jailbroken and you give it to someone, then there is no reason for concern?

Comment: I addressed that in the paragraph. If the owner jail broke it themselves why are they lending it out unless they really trust the person? I wouldn't even let a person make a call.